# Catch 404 errors in Asp.net Web API

Tags: asp.net, error-handling, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to catch 404 errors which are returned by the Asp.net Web API server.

However, `Application_Error` from inside Global.asax is not catching them.

Is there a way to handle these errors?

Comment: What goal you want to achieve by this?

Comment: I am trying to return a friendly error message to the user instead of returning the IIS HTML page. (The project is made to be requested only using API calls with JSON or XML responses)

Comment: Do you have full control over the `ApiController`s' code?

Answer (score 12):

You might want to take a look at [Handling HTTP 404 Error in ASP.NET Web API](http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2012/06/19/handling-http-404-error-in-asp-net-web-api.aspx) which has a step by step example

Comment: Thanks for the awesome link. I was looking for something like this just yesterday for my Web API Project and somehow it didn't show up on my search results.

Comment: That is a good link, thank you. Unfortunately, it won't catch all the 404 errors. For example, typing http://localhost:34123/xxyyzz doesn't gets caught.

Comment: unfortuntely I couldn't make this work because of using attribute routing.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old, but I was also just looking for this, and found a very easy way that seems to work, so thought I'd add incase this can help someone else.

The solution I found, that works for me, is [here](http://www.matrichard.com/post/WebAPI-catch-all-route-or-having-a-default-route-when-a-route-is-not-found). Also, this can be mixed with attribute routing (which I use).

So, in my (Owin) `Startup` class I just add something like..

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
{      
     HttpConfiguration httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();   
     //.. other config

     app.UseWebApi(httpConfig);

     //...
     // The I added this to the end as suggested in the linked post
     httpConfig.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "ResourceNotFound",
         routeTemplate: "{*uri}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Default", uri = RouteParameter.Optional });
    // ...

 }

  // Add the controller and any verbs we want to trap
  public class DefaultController : ApiController
  {
      public IHttpActionResult Get(string uri)
      {      
      return this.NotFound();
      }

      public HttpResponseMessage Post(string uri)
      {       
        HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "I am not found");
        return response;
      } 
   }
```

Above you can then return any error object (in this example I am just returning a string "I am not found" for my POST.

I tried the `xxyyzz` (no named controller prefix) as suggested by @Catalin and this worked as well.

Comment: Great Solution! This helped me with mine. However, I am unsure when I do `Get` and `Post`, it doesn't work. I must put `[HttpGet]` on function `Get` and `[HttpPost]` on function `Post`